# How can I rescue a Errno::ECONNRESET

Tags: ruby, error-handling, mechanize

I have a script that spiders a website, its based on Mechanize and seems to be working great except for what seems like an error I can't catch.  'Errno::ECONNRESET' This seems to reset the connection and print the error, but it doesn't seem to raise an exception.  What is the best way to deal with this?   I will put the program flow in pseudo code below.

```
while LinksQue.notEmpty
  begin
    mech.get(LinksQue.nextLink)
  rescue Mechanize::ResponseCodeError => e
    puts e.response_code
    puts "this is a bad link"
  rescue Errno::ECONNRESET
    #This doesn't work
  end
end
```

Part of my problem is that my method for marking a link as 'visited' or as a 'bad link' is a DB so unless I can update the DB in a rescue block it will just keep trying the same link again and again.

Comment: Are you sure that `Errno::ECONNRESET` is a subclass of `Exception`? Did you see `Errno::ECONNRESET.ancestors`?

Comment: @sawa Its ancestor chain is [Errno::ECONNRESET, SystemCallError, StandardError, Exception, Object, Kernal, BasicObject]

Comment: To me this means that its ancestor is Exception and I should be able to rescue it.  Am I interpreting this incorrectly?